# Python Loop To Print Asterisks Based on User Input

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a python program to print a certain number of asterisks based on user input. My code is below

```
num_stars = 3
num_printed = 0

while num_printed <= num_stars:
    print('*')
```

The output is an infinite loop. I want to print the number of stars variable as asterisks.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use

```
print num_stars * '*'
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that num_printed is not getting incremented.

In the while loop, add `num_printed += 1`, and change the condition to `num_printed < num_stars`, otherwise you will be printing 4 stars:

```
num_stars = 3
num_printed = 0

while num_printed < num_stars:
    print('*')
    num_printed += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment the num_printed variable.

```
num_stars = 3
num_printed = 0

while num_printed < num_stars:
    print('*')
    num_printed += 1
```

Also note that I changed the `<=` to `<`: you want to be checking for when `num_printed` is no longer less than the total number of stars, which will happen after the last start is counted, and your counter increments.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a loop here. Maybe do something like this:

```
stars = int(raw_input('number of stars: '))

star_list= ['*' for i in range(stars)]

print ' '.join(['%s' % i for i in star_list])
```

Answer (score 0):

While everybody -correctly- fixed your code, looking back at how you defined your project I would use the string/char multiply capabilities instead of a loop, as such:

```
    user_choice = input('How many stars?')
    num_stars = int(user_choice) * '*'
    print(num_stars)
```

Or, one liner:

```
    print(int(input('How many stars?')) * '*')
```